# Remove '-' and two following characters using regex?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have set of data from laboratory where data column looks like this:

```
12-15.11.12
19-22.11.12
26-29.11.12
03-06.12.12
10-13.12.12
17-20.12.12
19-23.12.12
27-30.12.12
02-05.01.13
```

I only want the first value (the day of sampling) so I can convert it into pandas datetime series etc. and continue working with data.

I know I can manually delete it in Excel but I would like to do it with the use of code. So my goal is for example:

12-15.11.12 -> 12.11.2012, '-15' gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub` with `-\d+` pattern ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/2e5VkP/1)):

```py
import re

data = '''\
12-15.11.12
19-22.11.12
26-29.11.12
03-06.12.12
10-13.12.12
17-20.12.12
19-23.12.12
27-30.12.12
02-05.01.13'''

data = re.sub(r'-\d+', '', data)
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
12.11.12
19.11.12
26.11.12
03.12.12
10.12.12
17.12.12
19.12.12
27.12.12
02.01.13
```

Answer (score 0):

import re

dates = [
"12-15.11.12",
"19-22.11.12",
"26-29.11.12",
"03-06.12.12",
"10-13.12.12",
"17-20.12.12",
"19-23.12.12",
"27-30.12.12",
"02-05.01.13"
]

cleaned_dates = []
for date in dates:
date = re.sub(r"(\d+)-\d+", r"\1", date)
cleaned_dates.append(date)

print(cleaned_dates)

Comment: Wrapping the source in triple backticks and adding comments might improve your answer.